# A table query that includes some ids and excludes others with pagination. SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, union

I am working with a table of users.

I have 2 lists. The first one consists of IDs, which must be in the answer and must come first. The second one consists of IDs, which should not be in the answer.

In this case, pagination should work.

I tried to split the query into 2 queries and use "UNION", it works but the results are scatter.

```
   `find_ids = [5, 6, 7]
    exclude_ids = [2]

    query1 = User.query.filter(User.id.in_(find_ids) & User.id.notin_(exclude_ids))
    query2 = User.query.filter(User.id.notin_(find_ids) & User.id.notin_(exclude_ids))

    return query1.union(query2).paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page)`
```

In this example, I'm expecting elements with id's like this: `[5, 6, 7, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, ...]`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316864/151124) by [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) states that you cannot rely on the order of subselects in a `UNION`. Instead we need to apply an `ORDER BY` clause to the result of the `UNION`.  To obtain the desired ordering based on list membership we can use a `CASE` statement in the ORDER BY` clause, like this (I'm assuming that you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy):

```py
q1 = User.query.filter(
    User.id.in_(find_ids) & User.id.not_in(exclude_ids)
)
q2 = User.query.filter(
    User.id.not_in(exclude_ids) & User.id.not_in(find_ids)
)
subq = q1.union(q2).subquery()
q3 = (
    db.session.query(subq.c.users_id)
    .select_from(subq)
    .order_by(
        db.case(
            (subq.c.users_id.in_(find_ids), subq.c.users_id - 100),
            else_=subq.c.users_id,
        )
    )
)
print(q3.all())
```

The pure SQLAlchemy version would be

```py
with Session() as s:
    q1 = sa.select(User).where(
        User.id.in_(find_ids) & User.id.not_in(exclude_ids)
    )
    q2 = sa.select(User).where(
        User.id.not_in(exclude_ids) & User.id.not_in(find_ids)
    )
    subq = q1.union(q2).subquery()
    q3 = (
        sa.select(subq.c.id)
        .select_from(subq)
        .order_by(
            sa.case(
                (subq.c.id.in_(find_ids), subq.c.id - 100), else_=subq.c.id
            )
        )
    )
    result = s.scalars(q3)
    print(list(result))
```

Comment: I am getting `AttributeError: users_id`.

Also my IDs are stored in UUID format

Comment: I'm confused: if your ids are UUIDs, why are you comparing them to INTs in the question?